# How do I restore a missing base folder on the home path on a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 install?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I try to run `vagrant init` and `vagrant up` on a freshly installed Ubuntu 17.04 with Virtual Box and Vagrant installed, but the output for `vagrant up` is:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /home/james/base
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `vagrant` but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up) it state that your command aught to have been like so:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
```

Not

```
vagrant init
```

So your missing a `box` name, change it to the one your trying to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I know why it didn't work. I didn't specify anything for `vagrant init`.

This seems to work:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/zesty64
vagrant up
```

Yes George also recognized the error.